# When is a directory actually classed as been "accessed" on Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, directory

I have this Console Application that gets a directory and prints out the last time it was written to and the last time time it was accessed. I am using the following code for checking when it was written to: `Directory.GetLastWriteTime(path)` and the following code for checking when it was last accessed to: `Directory.GetLastAccessTime(path)`. You don't need to be much of a programmer to see that from that, I am using the correct methods.

Now the problem is that when I pass in top level C:\ (or any directory) to `path`, the access time *always* matches the write time. Even when I have just opened up a few files in top level C, but not written to it. See here:

[image: Opening the C:\ Drive and accessing a file]

However, when I run the code I supplied to at the top I get this:

[image: Wrong time]

This was not the time I just opened that file. So now that leads me to believe that "accessing" a file is not what I think. Is that true, or is it a bug somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default configuration, Windows doesn't keep track of the last access times for directories.

You can turn this on using:

```
fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 0
```

However, this may affect system performance.